# Insert missing month in series in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, partitioning

I have a WITH table that partitions by id and counts the number of items that the user have created up to a certain month:

```
|      ID |  COUNT |   MONTH |
------------------------------
|       1 |      1 | 2013-01 |
|       1 |      2 | 2013-05 |
|       2 |      1 | 2013-02 |
|       2 |      2 | 2013-04 |
|       2 |      3 | 2013-06 |
|       3 |      1 | 2013-01 |
```

In postgresql, how can you add count onto months that are missing to create a final query result like this?

```
|      ID |  COUNT |   MONTH |
------------------------------
|       1 |      1 | 2013-01 |
|       1 |      1 | 2013-02 |
|       1 |      1 | 2013-03 |
|       1 |      2 | 2013-04 |
|       1 |      2 | 2013-05 |
|       1 |      3 | 2013-06 |
|       2 |      1 | 2013-02 |
|       2 |      1 | 2013-03 |
|       2 |      2 | 2013-04 |
|       2 |      2 | 2013-05 |
|       2 |      3 | 2013-06 |
|       3 |      1 | 2013-01 |  
|       3 |      1 | 2013-02 |  
|       3 |      1 | 2013-03 |
|       3 |      1 | 2013-04 |
|       3 |      1 | 2013-05 |
|       3 |      1 | 2013-06 |
```

Comment: Your second table seems to imply that the user has been active every month...

Comment: What datatype is the MONTH field, text?

Comment: The second table is what I am trying to achieve, the Month field is text (TO_CHAR(users.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming MONTH is some form of text field:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id, "count", month)
SELECT t1.id, t1."count", TO_CHAR(r.d, 'YYYY-MM')
FROM myTable as t1
JOIN (SELECT generate_series((min(month) || '-01')::date, 
                                   date_trunc('month',now())::date, 
                                   '1 month') as d
            FROM myTable) AS r 
  ON (t1.month || '-01')::date < r.d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM myTable as t2
  WHERE t1.id = t2.id 
    AND ( (t1."count" < t2."count" AND (t2.month || '-01')::date <= r.d)
         OR (t1."count" = t2."count" AND (t2.month || '-01')::date = r.d))
);
```

Working sqlfiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/69883/3).

Comment: What about the rest of the months in the year? And why is it always one when `COUNT` is cumulative?

Comment: @muistooshort: I hadn't noticed the cumulative count - although the desired data given seems to conflict on this point.  I'll update for this.

Comment: @PinnyM `INSERT INTO` would not work as the table in question is generated through a query.

Comment: @killergorillav, if you want to add this onto a cte, simply replace the INSERT INTO with a UNION to your CTE (or 'WITH' table).

Comment: @PinnyM here is a sqfiddle of my CTE so far, how do I `UNION` it on? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/31ff8/3

Comment: @killergorillav: you can change your CTE to look like [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/31ff8/38) and then you can use UNION to add on the query I suggested as you can see [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/31ff8/44).

Answer (score 0):

This can be considerably simpler.

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(id int, ct int, month text);

INSERT INTO tbl (id, ct, month)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2013-01'),
    (1, 2, '2013-05'),
    (2, 1, '2013-02'),
    (2, 2, '2013-04'),
    (2, 3, '2013-06'),
    (3, 1, '2013-01');
```

I substituted `ct` for the function name `count`, which I wouldn't use as identifier.
Assuming that `ct` (count) is never lower than 1 and never decreases over time for a given `id`, you can use this query (updated):

```
SELECT id.id, max(COALESCE(t.ct, 1)) OVER (PARTITION BY id.id 
                                           ORDER BY m.month) AS ct, m.month
FROM   generate_series(1,3) id
CROSS  JOIN (
   SELECT to_char('2013-1-1'::timestamp
          + interval '1 month' * generate_series(0,5), 'YYYY-MM') AS month
   ) m
LEFT   JOIN tbl t USING (id, month)
ORDER  BY id, month;
```

Now extended for an arbitrary series of months.

[**->SQLfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/23f91/2)

Comment: @erwin-branstetter but this does not consider when the user first created something. For example, user 2 did not created the first item until 2013-02, so in 2013-01 the CT should be '0', not '1'

Comment: @killergorillav: You are right, I didn't pay attention to the details. Can the series of numbers in `count` ever decrease for the same `id` over time? Or are numbers always increasing (or stay the same)? I added a query built on this premise.

Comment: Same problem, the 'count' for id=1 and month='2013-06' should be 2 since the closest entry given (that is an earlier date) is 2.  Also, as @muistooshort mentioned on my original answer, this is limited to working for the year '2013' with months 1 through 9.

Comment: @PinnyM: Right, my initial query was incorrect. I think the update should fix that (now with the missing `PARTITON BY`).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter the series of number will never decrease.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, yes PARTITION BY is much simpler than EXISTS that I am using - but you may want to improve series generation to include other months/years as needed.

Comment: @PinnyM: The question was as specific as my answer. I extended now for any series of months.

Comment: @killergorillav: Well, then my answer should fit your case.